# How do i draw a line using canvas in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to draw a line using canvas in ontouch event in android.

Here is my code:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        invalidate();
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        invalidate();
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);
        mPath.reset();
        invalidate();
    break;
}
```

But the line appears when I remove my finger from the mouse button that means the line appears only in the `touchesup` action. I want do draw a line like a freehand drawing.

Comment: so it should be curved with your finger movement as well?

Comment: ACTION_UP is only called when you release the touch.  You need to add to the line Path and draw it in ACTION_MOVE.

Answer (score 0):

you call drawPath only when you do action up. so if you copy your drawPath to all cases sit should work

Answer (score 0):

In your `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event handling code you use `mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);` to draw the line.

Add this line of code in other event handling code parts (`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`) and it will draw the line earlier as well.